# SQL Deleting All Records If ColA Matches and ColB Matches Sometimes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to delete all records from a SQL table where ColumnA matches an ID that sometimes has ColumnB equal 0.  In other words, if any data for an ID is bad, get rid of all data.

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
-------    -------
     11          0
     11          1
     11          0
     12          1
     12          1
```

In this data, I would want to delete anything where ColumnA is 11 because sometimes ColumnB is 0.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are  using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI standard syntax is:

```
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ColumnA = t.ColumnA and t2.ColumnB = 0
                 );
```

You can also use `in`:

```
delete from t
    where t.ColumnA in (select t2.ColumnA
                        from t t2
                        where t2.ColumnB = 0
                       );
```

Comment: I was overthinking it by a long shot.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as:

```
delete from tablename
where columnA in (select columnA from tablename where columnB = 0)
```